# Improve performance of large document text tokenization through Python + RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk, gensim

I'm currently trying to process a large amount of very big (>10k words) text files. In my data pipeline, I identified the gensim tokenize function as my bottleneck, the relevant part is provided in my MWE below:

```
import re
import urllib.request

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teropa/nlp/master/resources/corpora/genesis/english-web.txt'
doc=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

PAT_ALPHABETIC = re.compile('(((?![\d])\w)+)', re.UNICODE)

def tokenize(text):
    text.strip()
    for match in PAT_ALPHABETIC.finditer(text):
        yield match.group()

def preprocessing(doc):
    tokens = [token for token in tokenize(doc)]
    return tokens

foo=preprocessing(doc)
```

Calling the `preprocessing` function for the given example takes roughly `66ms` and I would like to improve this number. Is there anything I can still optimize in my code? Or is my hardware (Mid 2010s Consumer Notebook) the issue? I would be interested in the runtimes from people with some more recent hardware as well.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your regex is rather.... You should just use `PAT_ALPHABETIC = re.compile(r'[^\W\d]+')`. The `re.UNICODE` is redundant in Python 3.x

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for your answer. The regex originates from the gensim source code.. As far as I can tell, your suggestion seems to work as well and improves the runtime by roughly 30%

Comment: remove `text.strip()`

Comment: Yeah, that does not do anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
PAT_ALPHABETIC = re.compile(r'[^\W\d]+')

def tokenize(text):
    for match in PAT_ALPHABETIC.finditer(text):
        yield match.group()
```

Note:

- `\w` matches letters, digits, underscores, some other connector punctuation and diacritics in Python 3.x by default, you do not need to use `re.UNICODE` or `re.U` options
- To "exclude" (or "subtract") digit matching from `\w`, the `((?!\d)\w)+` looks an overkill, all you need to do is to "convert" the `\w` into an equivalent negated character class, `[^\W]`, and add a `\d` there: `[^\W\d]+`.
- Note the extraneous `text.strip()`: Python strings are immutable, if you do not assign a value to a variable, there is no use in `text.strip()`. Since whitespace in the input string do not interfere with the regex, `[^\W\d]+`, you may simply strip this `text.strip()` from your code.